# Submit button open a link in a new tab but should not

Tags: html, ajax

When I push the "Sign in" button the submit function is called.
For some reason the info that is supposed to be displayed opens in a new tab 
but it should not.

I am displaying info on a spark server.

Any ideas why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello world</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- load bootstrap for nicer ui -->
   <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

      <form method="post" action="/print" class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="y" id="y" placeholder="Y-Hnit">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="x" id="x" placeholder="X-Hnit">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="player" id="player" placeholder="playerid">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
      </form>
      <hr>
      <div id="results">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- load jquery -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- use ajax to submit form, retreive the result and display on the page -->
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var form = $('form');
      form.submit(function(e) {
        var y = $("#y")val();
        var x = $("#x").val();
        var player = $("#player").val();
        $.ajax({
          type: form.attr('method'),
          url: form.attr('action'),
          data: 'y=' + y + '&x=' + x + "&player" + player
        }).done(function(String) {
          $('#results').html(String).attr('class', 'alert alert-success');
        }).fail(function(String) {
          $('#results').html("bluuu").attr('class', 'alert alert-danger');
        });
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check your console?

Answer (score 1):

Add an `id` in your form `id="form"` and your script should be like so:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('submit','#form',function(){
        var info = $('#form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: /print,
           data: info,
           success: function(data){
            if(data){
            $('#results').html(data).attr('class', 'alert alert-success');
            }else{
             $('#results').html("bluuu").attr('class', 'alert alert-danger');
            }
          }
        });
   });
  });
```

**Edit:** Make sure the function `print` will check if there is an ajax response `else` will return `null`.